# How to add Lua libraries into a project and use "require" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, require

I am quite new to Lua and couldn't information as to how to add Lua libraries into a project and use "require" in Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 1):

You can define your [package.path](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-package.path) and [package.cpath](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-package.cpath) in your `launch.json` file for the project.

your configuration would look something like this:

```json
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "lua",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.lua",
        "path": "${workspaceFolder}/?.lua;C:\\lua\\?.lua"
    }
]
```

how these variable work with `require` is explained in
[Programming in Lua: 8.1 – The require Function](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Nifim's answer.

I faced the same problem using the Lua debugger extension "Lua Debug" made by `actboy168`. When using this extension, the `package.path` and `package.cpath` variable defaults to include your workspace folder only. Therefor, most of the packages installed in `/usr/local/lib/lua` on unix systems using the luarocks package manager cannot be found when press f5 to debug your lua script.

Here's an example of a `launch.json` file that enables you to use such a lua library:

```json
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "lua",
        "name": "launch lua debug",
        "cpath": "/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/?.so",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "request": "launch",
    },
]
```

The field `cpath` is usd to search for .so(or probably .dll on windows) files while `path` is used to search for lua scripts.